# Ubuntu missing after installing windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

So I had a dual system with Windows 7 and Ubuntu, I installed Windows 10 today in the partition of Windows 7, hoping the dual boot will stay the same, but now its missing, and I dont know if ubuntu was erase.
I have try with this command `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

and dissable windows 10 fast run or something like that, so anybody knows how can I get my dual boot menu again, or how to know if windows 10 deleted ubuntu somehow.

Comment: Follow this article https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: I get the menu now, but it doesnt load my ubuntu profile lets say.